# (Closed) Gradle imports in VS Code failing

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, dependencies

I'm working on a Gradle project in VS Code, but my dependencies aren't resolved. It does not complain in the build.gradle file, however the imports simply don't work inside the source files.

However I know for sure that the import statements are correct since the code is cloned and unmodified from a repository and I know that the code works in this state. The other creator did however use IntelliJ.

Someone has an idea why this does not work? I've got all kinds of gradle extensions installed.

Comment: What dependency did you use? The current description about question is too ambiguous to reproduce the unresolved import error.

Comment: How's your gradle project like? Is it convenient for you to post it in github?

Comment: No, I cannot post the github link, but it seems to have fixed itself. I honestly don't really know what I did but it works, so whatever.